# Firebase: Keep GeoFire coordinates private

Tags: firebase, geolocation, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

My application queries within a certain range for geolocation points.  The problem is that anyone could access the API directly to see the exact coordinates of the points.  These locations are user-generated, so I don't want them publicly visible, that would be a breach of the user's privacy.

How can I get the keys within the search area, without allowing read access to the actual coordinates?  I fear the only option may be to set up a separate application server to make the query and filter out the location information.

Comment: To secure the Firebase database, read about its security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have read through that documentation.  Of course I can authenticate someone, but I can't prevent any one user from seeing the coordinates of every other user via the API without disabling the distance querying I need to do.

Comment: In order to be able to query, the user needs to be able to read the data they're querying. That is inherent to Firebase's querying model and we often summarize it as "rules are not filters". You can find a lot more about that topic in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) and here [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I do understand that.  This does seem like a problem that other people are likely to need to solve as well.  Querying for nearby users without revealing their exact location exists in other apps.  Is this impossible with Firebase?